# Rational Application Developer: find the IDE's location on disk (from within the IDE)

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad

I have an open instance of Rational Application Developer - an eclipse-based IDE developed by IBM. RAD is newly installed, and i haven't yet created a shortcut. So, before closing it, i would like to create a shortcut. The problem is i forgot the place where i installed it. **Is there any way, from within the IDE (some of its menus, perhaps), to find the location of the IDE (the .exe file) on disk?**

Note 1: unlike eclipse, RAD has no 'Installation Details' under Help menu

Note 2: I already found a way to see the IDE's location: from Start, in the "Search Programs and Files" box, i type "rational" and it shows me the program ; i right click, select Properties, and under the Shortcut tab, the 'Start in'  field shows the containing folder of the IDE. However, this only works because the application is pinned to the Start menu. In case I delete the pin accidentally, or the pin is not even created on installation, because i don't check the corresponding box, the question still stands: how to find the IDE's location from within the IDE, not from outside it.

Comment: Installation Details is also a button on the 'Help > About' dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse you would go to `Help -> Installation Details -> Configuration tab`
However, in RAD, there is no `Installation Details` under `Help`. Fortunately, it is accessible this way: `Help -> About Rational® Application Developer -> Installation Details`. Credit goes to [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) for pointing this out.

In the `Installation Details` window, under the `Configuration tab`, the  relevant snippet is the following

```
-launcher
C:\Users\user_name\IBM_85\SDP\eclipse.exe
```

as a comparison, in eclipse it would look something like

```
-launcher
C:\Users\user_name\eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

this information is also contained in the line starting with `eclipse.home.location`

Comment: please see 'Note 3' which i have added 5 mins ago

Comment: your solution works for eclipse, indeed, but not for RAD; i am currently editing the question to reflect that

Comment: that's a pity... it still answers the heading of your question ;) maybe you can try a workaround? Click on `Help -> Install New Software` then search for a blueish link style text `What is already installed?` and klick on it. It should open the same window as `Installation Details`.

Comment: Another way I just found: click on `Navigate -> Open Setup -> Installation` it will show you some configuration file and also indicates where the installation directory is.

Comment: 1.   under Navigate, there is no 'Open Setup' (remember i use RAD, not eclipse). There is also no possible way to add it: Window>Customize Perspective>Menu Visibility: under Navigate, there is no "Open Setup" to check to make it visible in the menu      2.    greg-449's comment helped me reach the 'Installation Details' in RAD as well. I checked the Configuration tab, its content differs substantially between RAD and eclipse, however, it contains the information that i need. I will accept your answer, but i will modify it substantially in order to reflect the context of RAD